# Keeping the same volume while moving from pull ups to archer or uneven

Tags: bodyweight-exercises, pull-ups

I want to change the pull up variation from regular to archer or uneven (when you place on arm above the other) but I don’t know how to keep the same volume. I usually do 3 sets of 9 or 10 reps, so how is that going to transfer to uneven? I’m not talking about the reps but about the sets, because when you do uneven’s you have to work each arm separately, so should I do 2 sets for each arm or 3 sets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I **usually** do 3 sets of 9 or 10 reps

That's a red flag. Why do you have a "usual" set/rep range? The key to training is variety (and I'm gonna be repeating that a few times in this answer).

Variety in the set/rep numbers, but also in intensity. Do you ever strap on some extra weight and do, say, a few sets of 3-4 really heavy pullups? Because if not, then you definitely should.

> so how is that going to transfer to uneven?

It doesn't. The set/rep numbers aren't important anyway (unless you're testing your max), so there's no point trying to transfer them from one exercise to another.

There is no "best" number of sets/reps. There's variety, and you should always have variety.

Archers and unevens are exercises that are quite different from regular pullups, so you shouldn't think about transferring the usual set/rep numbers. It's a new exercise, so treat it as such.

You should do archers and unevens in a set/rep range that makes sure you work each side an equal amount. In effect, you start from scratch to figure out what works for these exercises.

> so should I do 2 sets for each arm or 3 sets?

There's no correct answer to this. For one thing, why would you even want to do the same number of sets every time?

Say you do 2 sets of 6 reps this time, then 3 sets of 4 reps next time. And maybe strap on some weight and do 3 sets of 2 heavy reps another time...

There are so many combinations of set/rep/weight numbers, and you should never limit yourself to just one of them. The key, again, is variation.

Comment: Is variation good to build strength?

Comment: @Yassir - Yessir.